# How to fix 500 Internal Server Error with LimitInternalRecursion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am facing 500 Internal Server Error on my local. It throws below error

```
[Thu Apr 02 22:03:18.752444 2020] [core:error] [pid 3996:tid 1180] [client ::1:9949] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

And my `.htaccess` file is

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to trailing slash.
RewriteRule ^/japan-constitution(.*) /japan-constitution/$1 [R=301,L]

# Handle 404
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /interactive/japan-constitution/404.html [L]
```

I have tried many ways to fix it. but it is not solved. If anybody help that will be helpful for me

Comment: Your last rewrite rule is going to redirect literally everything, in an infinite loop, because the regex `^` matches everything.

Comment: @ceejayoz Although the preceding rule prevents further processing when the request maps to a physical file - which the last rule appears to be rewriting to. So, there shouldn't be a rewrite loop if `/interactive/japan-constitution/404.html` exists as a physical file?

Comment: _Aside:_ Your first `RewriteRule` will never match in `.htaccess` - so it's not doing anything. However, it seems a little odd that that directive appears to be checking for `/japan-constitution` in the document root, whereas your later rule rewrites to a directory of the same name but in an `/interactive` subdirectory? Why are you seemingly rewriting to your 404 error document, instead of using an `ErrorDocument`? You should not "fix" this with `LimitInternalRecursion` - despite what the error reports (and your title requests).